# How to package HTML5 app?

Tags: web-applications, html5

There is some information about how to package HTML5 app to use on Android or iOS, but I couldn't find anything about a normal website.

Let's say I would like to create a website displaying multiple HTML5 interactive animations/apps, and I would like to have clear way of adding more of them. With SWF files the problem is easily solvable because the whole app can be contained in a single file that could be uploaded and embedded in a proper place. But how to achieve that with HTML5 apps?

App developer should have clear guidelines of how to develop an app to be easily uploaded, and someone else should be able to easily upload it without any technical knowledge. Is it possible?

I looked into tools like:

- https://github.com/remy/inliner
- https://github.com/Automattic/juice

And it looks like theoretically they could make all resources of the app inlined, and effectively make a single file app from them, assuming proper app's architecture, but I'm not sure if it would be really feasible.

Can HTML5 app be relatively easily packaged into single file, that can be uploaded and added to website just like SWF? Or the only option is taring the app and a lot of server-side magic?

Comment: see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Any suggestion how could I improve the question or where should I post it then?

Comment: did you check meta guidance referred in prior comment? There is a section "So what should be asked instead"

Comment: I did, but it doesn't help me. I'm not asking if it is possible to design something in the certain way, and I'm not looking for any expertise. At core my question is only about tools. Do tools/standards for packaging HTML5 apps for web usage exist or not. If not then I would have to come up with my own. I'm sorry if I worded it wrongly.

Comment: tools and external resource recommendations are off-topic per [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

I used NW.js for something similar before. On the other hand you could use something like the Qt WebEngine.

Here you can find the documentation for nw.js http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Getting%20Started/

"Further, you can easily package a web application to a native application."

The packaging is quite easy, as you only need to create a zip file of your application and rename it to package.nw. The binary of nw.js will look in its folder for  this package.nw file and execute it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Electron to create an executable version of your website for desktop or Cordova to create an executable version of your website for mobile.

- https://electron.atom.io/
- https://cordova.apache.org/